# Crash inside fork(); forking from a different thread eliminates the crash

Tags: segmentation-fault, fork, vxworks

TLDR: In the situation outlined below if I call `fork()` it crashes.  If I `fork()` on a new thread it does ***not*** crash.  What could they be doing that would cause `fork()` to crash?

---

I'm working on something that runs inside `vxsim` (a VxWorks emulation environment) and while exploring some of its limits I ran into this problem.

`vxsim` runs as a single-threaded process with its own internal task scheduler.  It uses `itimer()` (`SIGALRM`) to simulate the appropriate interrupt, during which time it uses `setcontext()` (in Solaris; in Linux it does something similar) to make the current (only) thread resume execution on a different task.

There's little or no real distinction between "sim" functions and "host" functions.  The ABI is the same; if you happen to have the address to a host function (eg, `fork()`) it can be called directly.
The only catch is there's a function that should be called first that disables simulated interrupts & the like.

As an experiment I made it call `fork()` and it crashes during that call.  If instead I create a new thread then `fork()` on the new thread it does not crash.

The simulation behaves this way on both x86 Linux & sparc Solaris 10.

For comparison I did the same thing in a much older version of VxWorks (5.x) and it works just fine.

What I'm fishing for is an answer to this question:

> What could they be doing that would cause `fork()` to crash like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [erroneous] [bug report](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=4067) filed against glibc where the OP [more or less] writes:

> I called `sigaction()` with a mostly un-initialized struct instance
> when setting up a handler for `SIGCHLD`.  Later, when I call `fork()`
> and the `SIGCHLD` handler executes, my program crashes.

I managed to prove they are indeed doing exactly that in their code in at least one spot.  To test whether that was the culprit I then zero-initialized the stack below `%ESP` before the offending function gets called.  Unfortunately it's still crashing, though I think it's very likely there's other spots doing this sort of thing.

Adding insult to injury the company is unwilling to fix it unless we pay extra.  Sigh.